# develop a function in kotlin using WorkManager + Socket

Tags: kotlin, socket.io, android-workmanager

it's for college work, I worked as an uber driver for a while and I took on the challenge of developing the function of that driver button to trust online, which after online it receives a ride and if you click again it goes offline,the idea of ​​work is that it works even with the app minimized, and when the user's cell phone is restarted, the uber service also works after the restart, I'm using kotlin and I chose WorkManager, it has Work,CoroutineWorker,ListenableWorker
[buttonUber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBaLZ.jpg)

in this code I made using CoroutineWorker it stays active while the count is done, after that it closes

`
class NotificationWorker (context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(context, params) {

```
override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
    return withContext(IO) {
        Log.i("MYTAG", "Started ${getCurrentDateTime()}")
        return@withContext try {
            for (i in 0..100) {
                delay(1000)
                           }
              success()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.i("MYTAG", "Exception $e")
            failure()
        }
    }
}`
```

in this other example using ListenableWorker it works the way I expect it, on and off by the button, but for it to work I'm trapping the completer inside FirebaseAuth and it doesn't seem the best way to do it, to be a hacker.

`public class CallbackWorker  extends ListenableWorker {

```
public CallbackWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
    super(appContext, workerParams);

    mContext=appContext;
    myAppsNotificationManager = MyAppsNotificationManager.getInstance(appContext);
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Tests);
    geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);

}
@NonNull
@Override
public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {

    //Icone Notification
    getForegroundInfoAsync();

    return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
             startListen(completer);
        return  completer;
    });

}

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void startListen(CallbackToFutureAdapter.Completer<Result> completer) {
    // monitorando se o gps ta ativo
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                      .setPriority(Priority.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addIdTokenListener(new FirebaseAuth.IdTokenListener() {
        @Override
        public void onIdTokenChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
                TokenRefresh();
                completer.set(Result.failure());
            }
        }
    });
}
LocationCallback locationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {

    }
};`
```

I'm looking for help because I don't know if I'm going the right way, when I hear the fast socket connection my work closes, I've tried all possible ways.